# How to oAuth weather yahoo api

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy, weather-api

I use this code to access weather data from yahoo and everything just work fine.
Somehow this stops working getting a "Bad request" from yahoo...

"Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="OST_OAUTH_PARAMETER_ABSENT_ERROR", realm="yahooapis.com"
"

I try to understood what happed and i think that has to do with the oAuth from yahoo but i don't know how to use it and the documentation from yahoo sucks...

code below..

`mForcastTown.Add(MainForm.ExtraFE_IdHttp.Get('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w='+ mAdd_Town[mTonwNum].mWoeID +'&u='+ mAdd_Town[mTonwNum].mDegree);`

Thank you...

UPDATE...

I found this below and when run in the browser i get the xml i need but when i run it to the

```
IdHttp.get('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid=55903793%20and%20u=%27c%27&format=xml')
```

i get unknown version found...

What is this... 
Thank you...

Comment: You have to provide OAuth authentication information to be able to access this API.

Comment: smooty86... i figure this out but i dont know how to do this do you have any example to help me... thanks...

Comment: You can read it ... it is probably enough when you complete these steps once in a browser and then just reuse your "key" (add it as custom header IdHttp.Requests.CustomHeaders['OAuth']="your key"). Docs: https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/

Comment: @smooty86: The correct way to provide OAuth parameters is with the `Authorization` header, not the `OAuth` header.  For OAuth 1, use: `IdHttp.Requests.CustomHeaders['Authorization'] := 'OAuth <parameters>';` For OAuth 2, use: `IdHttp.Requests.CustomHeaders['Authorization'] := 'Bearer <base64 encoded parameters>';` See [Using OAuth in Yahoo API Requests](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-make-request.html) and [Making API Requests](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/apirequests/)

Comment: Sorry for that misinformation. I was in a hurry and that was meant as an example. I did not think it through.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  In idHttp i don't have Requests but Request... so i cant call it that way bcs .... it is like this... idHttp.Request.CustomHeaders[1]:= 'text....' so i can't put the word 'Authorization'... Thanks

Comment: @azrael11 use `IdHttp.Request.CustomHeaders.Values ['Authorization']`

Comment: Yahoo want to request "get_request_token" before get the token and write it after bearer... but when i call     mForcastTown.Add(MainForm.ExtraFE_IdHttp.Get('http://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token?'+
    '&oauth_nonce=123456787654321qwertrewq'+
    '&oauth_timestamp=1202956957'+
    '&oauth_consumer_key=my key'+
    '&oauth_singature_method=plaintext'+
    '&oauth_singature=my secret'+
    '&oauth_version=1.0'+
    '&xoauth_lang_pref="en-us"'+
    '&oauth_callback=oob'));   i get authorization requared... i confuse... any help... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for Java, maybe this will direct you to something.

In this [link](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html) there is a sample java code:

```
    // Copyright 2019 Oath Inc. Licensed under the terms of the zLib license see https://opensource.org/licenses/Zlib for terms.
    import javax.crypto.Mac;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Base64;
    import java.util.Base64.Encoder;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.net.URLEncoder;
    import java.net.http.HttpClient;
    import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
    import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
    import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers;
    import java.net.URI;

    /**
    *
    * <pre>
    * % java --version
    * % java 11.0.1 2018-10-16 LTS
    *
    * % javac WeatherYdnJava.java && java -ea WeatherYdnJava
    * </pre>
    *
    */
    public class WeatherYdnJava {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            final String appId = "test-app-id";
            final String consumerKey = "your-consumer-key";
            final String consumerSecret = "your-consumer-secret";
            final String url = "https://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/forecastrss";

            long timestamp = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
            byte[] nonce = new byte[32];
            Random rand = new Random();
            rand.nextBytes(nonce);
            String oauthNonce = new String(nonce).replaceAll("\\W", "");

            List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
            parameters.add("oauth_consumer_key=" + consumerKey);
            parameters.add("oauth_nonce=" + oauthNonce);
            parameters.add("oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1");
            parameters.add("oauth_timestamp=" + timestamp);
            parameters.add("oauth_version=1.0");
            // Make sure value is encoded
            parameters.add("location=" + URLEncoder.encode("sunnyvale,ca", "UTF-8"));
            parameters.add("format=json");
            Collections.sort(parameters);

            StringBuffer parametersList = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.size(); i++) {
                parametersList.append(((i > 0) ? "&" : "") + parameters.get(i));
            }

            String signatureString = "GET&" +
                URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                URLEncoder.encode(parametersList.toString(), "UTF-8");

            String signature = null;
            try {
                SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec((consumerSecret + "&").getBytes(), "HmacSHA1");
                Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
                mac.init(signingKey);
                byte[] rawHMAC = mac.doFinal(signatureString.getBytes());
                Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
                signature = encoder.encodeToString(rawHMAC);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to append signature");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            String authorizationLine = "OAuth " +
                "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + consumerKey + "\", " +
                "oauth_nonce=\"" + oauthNonce + "\", " +
                "oauth_timestamp=\"" + timestamp + "\", " +
                "oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", " +
                "oauth_signature=\"" + signature + "\", " +
                "oauth_version=\"1.0\"";

            HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(url + "?location=sunnyvale,ca&format=json"))
                .header("Authorization", authorizationLine)
                .header("X-Yahoo-App-Id", appId)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();

            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
            System.out.println(response.body());
        }
    }
```

The problem with this code is where the `oauthNonce` generated with random bytes. Here, the error is caused by the unrecognized chars. Because for any random byte there can be any char that your system doesn't recognize and can't process because it converts it into a string.

I replace the whole part with this:

```
String oauthNonce = RandomStringUtils.random(10, true, true);
```

It worked like a charm. I currently don't have any errors now and able to get the response. I hope this helps.